# HTML& CSS: fullwidth element with first column fixed width and second column covering rest of the width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to achieve this behavior [here](http://jsbin.com/eyagoq/4/edit) ( see Right Example ) - where the first child is fixed width and the second is responsive ( covers the rest of the width )

I can do it with tables, but webheads will argue that tables are outdated for this kind of layout etc. + table display is resource heavy. Hmm

Any idea how to do it without the table markup ? At least would be cool to have divs but with display:table applied to them, but have not succeeded that either ( see Test Example )

Comment: I'd add different arguments against tables. Firstly, they aren't responsive as they don't allow the content to be reflowed on narrow displays, and secondly they semantically describe a table of data, which isn't what you're displaying. I'm a pragmatist, so I find the first argument more convincing than the second, but not everybody feels the same way.

Comment: I agree @Richard Marr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
#left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPQwL/)

Comment: would have never thought of that

Comment: 'Clearing' floats is one of the lesser known features of `overflow: hidden`. :D

Answer (score 2):

Put `width: 200px; float: left;` on the first element, and `overflow: hidden` on the second.